# Dagger inject on superclass and sub-class

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

BaseFragment class

```
open class BaseFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject lateinit var apiManager: ApiManager
    @Inject lateinit var eventBus: EventBus

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        App.getInstance().component.inject(this)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        eventBus.unreg(this)
        super.onStop()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        eventBus.reg(this)
    }
}
```

RoomsFragment class

```
class RoomsFragment : BaseFragment() {

    @Inject lateinit var roomAdapter: RoomsAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        App.getInstance().component.inject(this)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rooms_fragment_new, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        recyclerView.adapter = roomAdapter //This line throws null or lateinit property roomAdapter has not been initialized
    }
}
```

AdapterModule class

```
@Module(includes = AppModule.class)
public class AdapterModule {

    @Provides //App module has EventBus so i included it in Module
    RoomsAdapter provideRoomsAdapter(EventBus eventBus) {
        return new RoomsAdapter(eventBus);
    }
}
```

AppComonent class

```
@Singleton
    @Component(modules = {AppModule.class, AdapterModule.class})
    public interface ApplicationComponent {
        void inject(ApiManager apiManager);
        void inject(BaseFragment baseFragment);
    }
```

As you can see i'm trying to Inject objects in both superclass and sub class, but it is not not working as expected. `BaseFragment` Injected objects work find but `RoomsFragment` Injection fail. Any solution ?

Fix:
I forgot to add interface for sub-class`RoomsFragment` in ApplicationComponent. Since its superclass `BaseFragment` interface was present it was not throwing any error at compile time.

```
@Singleton
    @Component(modules = {AppModule.class, AdapterModule.class})
    public interface ApplicationComponent {
        void inject(RoomsFragment roomsFragment);
        void inject(ApiManager apiManager);
        void inject(BaseFragment baseFragment);
    }
```

Comment: you defined your RoomsFragment in your component?

Comment: Yes, I did.....

Comment: I hope this is not commented in your real code  App.getInstance().component.inject(this) in RoomsFragment.?

Comment: I tried both way. But no luck.

Comment: split the component and try.

Comment: Thanks @PushpendraChoudhary i did not create inject interface for RoomsFragment in AppComponent. App.getInstance().component.inject(this) was not throwing error because its superclass `BaseFragment`  was declared in AppComponent. Hope dagger2 team show do something for this because i have no idea whether sub-class has interface in AppComponent or not, until i manually check AppComponent.

Comment: So basically my first comment was the answer  :P I wrote an answer please accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131470/discussion-between-sai-kiran-and-pushpendra-choudhary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Singleton
        @Component(modules = {AppModule.class, AdapterModule.class})
        public interface ApplicationComponent {
            void inject(ApiManager apiManager);
            void inject(BaseFragment baseFragment);
            void inject(RoomsFragment roomsFragment);
        }
```

Answer (score 5):

The documentation of [members injection methods](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html#members-injection-methods) in the `@Component` documentation describes the relevant behavior.

It looks like you are trying to inject members of `RoomsFragment`.  By adding a method that accepts `RoomsFragment`, you will inject the `@Inject` members of `RoomsFragment` and any supertype (in this case `BaseFragment).

On the other hand, if you invoke a members injection method that accepts `BaseFragment`, you will inject the `@Inject` members of `BaseFragment`, but **not** any members of any subtype.  For that reason, it is almost never a good idea to define a members injection method for an abstract type.

In the original question, this is complicated by the fact that all of the members injection methods are defined as overloads of each other.  This means that you will get different injection behavior for a given type depending on how the overload is resolved.  See *Effective Java 2: Item 41* for more background on why these overloads are error-prone.

It is also worth noting that in the original code sample there is a members injection method for `ApiManager`, but that type is injected as an instance into `BaseFragment`.  Injecting members resolves dependencies transitively, so there is no need to define any method for `ApiManager` on the component.

So, in order to inject all of the members of `RoomsFragment` (declared and inhertied), just define one members injection method for `RoomsFragment`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, AdapterModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent {
  void inject(RoomsFragment roomsFragment);
}
```